# Facebook page like and twitter follow

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

is it possible to add facebook page like and twitter follow in UIActivityViewController of iPhone latest feature ??

I am using following code for sharing.

```
    NSString *message = [_mWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$(\"meta[property='og:description']\").attr(\"content\")"];
    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:[_mWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$(\"meta[property='og:url']\").attr(\"content\")"]];

    NSArray *activityItems = @[message, urlToShare];

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeMessage];

    [self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
```